# How Do I create a list from numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

How do I get numpy array into python list?

looking for ('foo', 1, 2, 3, 4)
series is a numpy array

```
symbol = 'foo'

def rowp (symbol,series):
            rowp=[]
            series = series[0:4]
            ss = series.tolist     
            rowp.append(symbol)     
            rowp.append(ss)      
            print rowp
```

I get error:

```
['foo', <built-in method tolist of numpy.ndarray object at 0x05D07D40>]
```

Comment: ok, But now I get ('foo', [1,2,3,4])  .....its late here....I thought I had called it..... How do I get ('foo', 1, 2, 3, 4)

Comment: use `rowp.extend` instead of `append`. Create a new question for these things

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can already see by the error message, [`tolist` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) is a **method**. That means you have to **call** it:

```
ss = series.tolist()
```

**Update:** Use `extend` instead of `append`:

```
rowp.extend(series.tolist())
```

---

Btw, the result you get is not an *error*.